# Tabela Frequencia Relativa - R / R Studio (% Diario Vendas Determinada Data/Produto)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Já tentei de todas as formas escrever um código que crie uma tabela de frequências relativas, mas não consegui. Tenho um dataframe com as seguintes variáveis:

- `RANGE_DIAS`: Intervalo de dias entre a data do pedido e o faturamento.
- `QTDE`: Quantidade faturada.
- `COD_PRODUTO`: Código do produto.
- `DATA`: Data do faturamento

O nome do dataframe é **tempo_atendimento**

Criei varios subsets (`var_temp`) com cada data e cada produto e juntei todos ao final (`df_temp`) porque não consegui descobrir como fazer a tabela com a frequencia relativa com a quantidade de produtos por dia.

Preciso de algo que gere a tabulação final sem precisar criar subsets separados e juntar todos no final. Algo que leia cada data e cada produto e calcule a frequencia relativa do dia e não do total geral do dataframe principal.

Estou usando os pacotes tidyverse e janitor.

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12e-SOwfRB_QlTCrd0o6S7mwyGzaS9R8oNPk79ripSgU/edit?usp=sharing]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  group_by(RANGE_DIAS) %>% 
  filter(DATA == "2020-11-20",
         COD_PRODUTO == "B41") %>% 
  tabyl(RANGE_DIAS) %>% 
  arrange(factor(RANGE_DIAS, levels = c("1 ~ 30", "31 ~ 60", "61 ~ 90",
                                       "91 ~ 120", "121 ~ 150", "151 ~"))) %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2, affix_sign = F)

var_temp <- var_temp %>% 
  mutate(COD_PRODUTO = "B41", DATA = "2020-11-20")

df_temp <- df_temp %>% 
  bind_rows(var_temp)

df_temp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carregando os pacotes e o xlsx:

```
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
df <- read_excel('./tempo_atendimento.xlsx')
```

Fazendo algumas conversões:

```
df$COD_PRODUTO <- as.factor(df$COD_PRODUTO)
df$RANGE_DIAS <- as.factor(df$RANGE_DIAS)
df$DATA <- ymd(df$DATA)
```

Aqui é onde geramos o novo data frame:

```
novo_df <- df %>% group_by(COD_PRODUTO, RANGE_DIAS, DATA) %>%
  summarise(QTDE = n()) %>%
  group_by(DATA, COD_PRODUTO) %>%
  mutate(FREQ = QTDE / sum(QTDE)) %>%
  arrange(DATA)
```

Fazemos um primeiro agrupamento por `COD_PRODUTO, RANGE_DIAS, DATA` e sumarizamos.

No outro passo agrupamos por `DATA` e `COD_PRODUTO`,criamos a frequência e organizamos pela data.

Saída:

```
    COD_PRODUTO         RANGE_DIAS     DATA        QTDE   FREQ
 1      A22               1 - 30    2020-11-19       2    0.0286
 2      A22              31 - 60    2020-11-19      10    0.143 
 3      A22              61 - 90    2020-11-19      57    0.814 
 4      A22              91 - 120   2020-11-19       1    0.0143
 5      A31              31 - 60    2020-11-19       1    0.0196
 6      A31              61 - 90    2020-11-19      32    0.627 
 7      A31              91 - 120   2020-11-19      18    0.353 
 8      B22               1 - 30     2020-11-19      1    0.0909
 9      B22              61 - 90    2020-11-19       2    0.182 
10      B22              91 - 120   2020-11-19       8    0.727 
...
```

Comment: Sensacional! Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda! Desejo que seu conhecimento se multiplique ainda mais! Grato! Funcionou perfeitamente, Excelente solução!

Comment: Opa! Que bom que te ajudou, fico feliz! Grande Abraço Max!